# MySQL UPDATE syntax error with variables

Tags: php, sql-update

Long story short, I'm trying to write a PHP code that will parse a text file into MySQL queries. Everything works fine except for the queries, which consist of UPDATE statements.

The entire code is kinda long, but if you want to see it - http://pastebin.com/xVR6ArD0

Here is just the part which is problematic :

```
while ($i<=$no_collumns)
           {
             $j = $i-1;
             if (!
                  mysql_query 
                  ("UPDATE ResultsPredmet 
                   SET ${parsed_collumns[$i]} = '${parsed_words[$j]}' 
                   WHERE ${parsed_first_collumn} LIKE '${parsed_first_word}'")
                ) 
              {echo mysql_error()."\n"; break;}
            // echo "\nUPDATE ResultsPredmet SET ${parsed_collumns[$i]} = '${parsed_words[$j]}' WHERE ${parsed_first_collumn} LIKE \"${parsed_first_word}\"";
         $i++;
         }
```

... where $parsed_collumns and $parsed_words are arrays of strings and $parsed_first_collumn and $parsed_first_word are strings.

I tried all combinations of quotes and escapes for the variables. I tried putting them in double quotes and escaping them, or double quotes and concatenating them, then maybe i thought it was the fact that I was comparing strings via the '=' operator so i tried with 'LIKE'. I googled for several hours and everywhere people said to use single quotation marks for variables so I tried that too and it didn't work.

In the end I echoed the queries and I get:

```
UPDATE ResultsPredmet SET grade = '10' WHERE name LIKE "Vildur"
UPDATE ResultsPredmet SET index = '117/2010' WHERE name LIKE "Vildur"
Updating table. 
UPDATE ResultsPredmet SET grade = '6' WHERE name LIKE "NinoDoko"
UPDATE ResultsPredmet SET index = '132/2011' WHERE name LIKE "NinoDoko"
Updating table. 
UPDATE ResultsPredmet SET grade = '10' WHERE name LIKE "Koco"
UPDATE ResultsPredmet SET index = '130/2011' WHERE name LIKE "Koco"
Done.
```

Which seem fairly fine to me. Other queries I got were the same only with the names with single quotes around them, or with no quotes or any other combinations.

The errors I get are :

```
Updating table. 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'index = '117/2010' WHERE name LIKE 'Vildur'' at line 1
Updating table. 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'index = '132/2011' WHERE name LIKE 'NinoDoko'' at line 1
Updating table. 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'index = '130/2011' WHERE name LIKE 'Koco'' at line 1
```

Apparently, the server that I'm using is MariaDB 5.5, but after a bit of research I figured it would be similar to just generic MySQL, though I might be completely off. The "Updating table." is just a random echo in my code. I've also tried the query without indenting it, still got the same errors. The values I get for `grade` and `index` are strings - or at least I hope so, since I'm getting them with `explode()`.

Comment: Replace double quotes by simple quotes (`LIKE "Vildur"` -> `LIKE 'Vildur'`). Plus, check that your `grade` field is really of `varchar` type, otherwise remove quotes around its values.

Comment: *Obligatory:* The `mysql_*` functions will be [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: @X.L.Ant I tried that as well, it still doesn't work. As I said, I tried all (well, most) combinations of quotes, but no dice.

Comment: Anyway, double quotes here are WRONG. Maybe there's another syntax error (see my updated comment), but this one is patent.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary I am aware, and I guess that will be my resort.

Comment: @X.L.Ant If I put single quotes, I literally get the same error, the only thing different is the queries if I echo them.

Comment: I understood the first time. Then you have another syntax error. But double quotes are one. If you keep them, your query will always fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

index is a reserved word

```
UPDATE ResultsPredmet SET `index` = '10' WHERE name LIKE 'Vildur'
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: Column names should be surrounded with backticks `, not '.

Comment: I absolutely love it when something so trivial is the reason I'm bashing my head off a wall for 3 hours. Thank you kindly good sir.